# Jquery Pagination with <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table>
  <tbody>
      <th></th>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
      ...
  </tbody>  
</table>

<a href="#">&lt;&lt;</a>
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="#">2</a>.
....
<a href="#">&gt;&gt;</a>
```

Here I want to make pagination that will show only 3 `<tr>`s each time. No of `<tr>` is dynamic. So page no will also be calculated. How can I do that?

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd make a function which sets a `current_row` variable and references it against `$('tr').eq(whatever)`. Make it iterate 3 times either direction, `show()` the applicable rows and `hide()` the `siblings()`

Comment: and how can u do this exactly ?? :D

Comment: @AlienWebguy Thanks for the fiddle. I was looking for something similar.

Comment: @AlienWebguy But, but when the `tr` items are over and we click it on next, it goes to first page. How to stop that?